# Invite friends to event facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My script is pretty slow when inviting users to event, because it has to check if user already is invited to the event, or else it will give a facebook ouath error.

Can i make it faster?

```
foreach ( $_POST['friends'] as $ids ) {
    if ( $i < 199 ) {
        $iZ = $facebook->api("/".$event_id."/invited/".$ids, "GET");
            if ( $iZ['data'][0]['rsvp_status']):
                    $status = $iZ['data'][0]['rsvp_status'];
            else:
                    $status="";
            endif;

    if ( ($status != 'declined' && $status != 'attending' && $status != "unsure" && $status !=     "not_replied") || empty($status)) {
            $id.=$ids . ",";
            $i=$i+1;
    }
 }
}

$id = substr_replace($id ,"",-1);


echo $facebook->api("/".$event_id . "/invited",'POST', array("users" => $id));
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Cbroe says, use FQL, here is the code:

```
SELECT uid,name FROM user WHERE uid IN 
(SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me()) AND NOT 
(uid IN (SELECT uid FROM event_member where eid = 306212359507086))
```

This will give you the list of friends not invited to that event.

Dont forget to change the event id

[Try it on Graph Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/465440490160635/?fql=SELECT%20uid%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%20%28%20SELECT%20uid1%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid2%3Dme%28%29%20%29%20%0AAND%20NOT%20%28uid%20IN%20%28SELECT%20uid%20FROM%20event_member%20where%20eid%20%3D%20306212359507086%29%29)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Two possible approaches:

- use [batch requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) to post the invite for each user id individually (individually, but still all with one request) – if single invite fails, that does not matter, the following invite posts will still be made.
- “cross-sect” your friend id list with the [FQL `event_members` table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event_member/) first – get the list of all event members that match your friend ids (using `WHERE eid='event_id' AND uid IN(…,…)`), and then “subtract” the result (people that have already been invited to the event) from your original friend id list. (In PHP you could use `array_diff` for that.)

Comment: I tried batch requests, but doesn't work properly, max 50 requests. How can i get the friendlist with friends there NOT are in my event?

Comment: So? Do _several_ batch requests, each containing 50 single invite posts.

Comment: `foreach ( $_POST['friends'] as $ids )
{

flush();
       $mybkey = $batch->add("/".$event_id."/invited/".$ids, 'GET');
       $batch->execute();
      $iZ = $batch->response($mybkey);
      if ( empty($iZ['data'][0]['rsvp_status'])):
         echo "Ikke inviteret.";
         $id.=$ids.",";
        $p=$p+1;
      endif;
  
  
}`