# get facebook friends which not are in events

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Invite friends to event facebook api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931129/invite-friends-to-event-facebook-api)

How do i get all my friends that not are in my event? (not are invited)

right now i just have this, but it just show all friends.

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
    foreach ($friends as $key=>$value) {
       foreach ($value as $fkey=>$fvalue) {
          if ( is_numeric ( $fvalue['id'] ) ) :
               echo '<div class="friends"><table><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="friends[]" value="' . $fvalue['id'] . '" checked="checked"/></td><td><img src="http://graph.facebook.com/' . $fvalue['id'] . '/picture" title="' . $fvalue['name'] . '"/></td><td><span style="color:#000"> '.$fvalue['name'].'</span></td></tr></table></div>';
          endif;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Follow-up of [Invite friends to event facebook api](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12931129/invite-friends-to-event-facebook-api)

Answer (score 0):

YOu can check if someone is invited with a http get (see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/ ) So first you get all the friends, then check if they are attending, if yes then don't show them, or show them in a grey color like facebook does, otherwise show them

This is btw the answer which facebook gives: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=331218348435/invited/2503747

Comment: I already do that, but if user has 900 friends it takes 100000 years to load the page

Comment: That is the problem with the whole graph api..